# How to fix NullPointerException in breath first search in java?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I try to construct a breath first search relationship(BFS) by using a txt file. It works perfectly when the BFS size is small(eg. 7nodes), but NullPointerException appears when the BFS size is big(eg. 20000nodes). I've already read some posts about NullPointerException, but I still have no idea on how to solve it.

The exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at GraphAdjacentList.setEdge(GraphAdjacentList.java:16)    
        at GraphAdjacentListDemo.main(GraphAdjacentDemo.java:52)
```

There are 7 nodes, then each line shows the relationship of two nodes.
The format of the txt file:

```
7
1 2
1 3
1 4
4 5
4 6
5 7
```

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GraphAdjacentListDemo{
/* to build an adjacentList */
final private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> Adjacent_List;
public GraphAdjacentListDemo(int numberOfVertices){
    Adjacent_List = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
    for(int i=1;i<=numberOfVertices;i++){
        Adjacent_List.put(i,new LinkedList<Integer>());
    }
}

public void setEdge(int source,int destination){
    List<Integer> sList = Adjacent_List.get(source);
    sList.add(destination);
    List<Integer> dList = Adjacent_List.get(destination);
    dList.add(source);
}

public List<Integer> getEdge(int source){
    return Adjacent_List.get(source);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    /* to import a node source file */
    File f = new File("/Users/apple/Desktop/Graph_Sample.txt");
    List<Integer> source = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int count=0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);


    while(sc.hasNextInt()){
        int i=0;
        i = sc.nextInt();   
        source.add(i);
        count++;
        }
        sc.close();

    /* to store nodes into source_array and destination_array */
    int time=(count-1)/2;
    List<Integer> sourceList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> destinationList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=1;i<=time;i++){
        sourceList.add(source.get(1+2*(i-1)));
        destinationList.add(source.get(2+2*(i-1)));
    }

    GraphAdjacentList adjacentList = new GraphAdjacentList(source.get(0));
    for(int i=0;i<sourceList.size();i++){
        adjacentList.setEdge(sourceList.get(i),destinationList.get(i));             
    }

    System.out.println("The graph is:\n");
    try{
    for(int i=1;i<=source.get(0);i++){
        System.out.print(i+"-->");
        List<Integer> edgeList = adjacentList.getEdge(i);
        for(int j=1;;j++){
            if(j != edgeList.size()){
                System.out.print(edgeList.get(j-1)+"-->");
            }else{
                System.out.print(edgeList.get(j-1));
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }catch(InputMismatchException inputMismatch){}


}

}
```

Comment: We can't reproduce this problem since you only gave us code if `GraphAdjacentListDemo` class but you are declaring `adjacentList` to be of `GraphAdjacentList` class, which we have no idea how it looks like.

Comment: I've closed your question as a duplicate of the canonical one. "I still have no idea how to solve it" is not an appropriate problem description. That canonical answer will explain how to debug NPE issues which is all that is needed to find your specific solution to the problem. Question your assumptions and fire up a debugger. Then, when you hit the exception, go back through the program flow to find out why something might not have had the value you thought it had.